# Why are my similar queries processed very differently?

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-performance

We have a table

> mysql> show create table channeldata\G
>   *************************** 1. row ***************************
>          Table: channeldata
>   Create Table: CREATE TABLE `channeldata` (
>        `channel_id` smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
>        `station_id`
>   smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
>        `time` datetime NOT NULL,
>   `reading` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>        `average` double NOT NULL
>   DEFAULT '0',
>        `location_lat` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>   `location_lon` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>        `location_alt`
>   double(8,3) DEFAULT '0.000',
>        `quality` smallint(3) unsigned
>   DEFAULT '0',
>   PRIMARY KEY (`channel_id`,`station_id`,`time`),
>   KEY `composite3` (`station_id`,`channel_id`,`quality`) USING BTREE,
>   KEY `composite` (`channel_id`,`station_id`,`time`,`quality`) USING
>   BTREE   ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
>   1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Recently I noticed some of the select queries we do are taking quite a long time to finish. The strange thing is that depending on the values of a column in the where clause a select completes either very fast or it takes a long time blocking updates to that same table. I ran these queries through explain:

> mysql> explain SELECT reading FROM channeldata WHERE station_id = 6001
>   AND channel_id = 1 AND time < '2018-09-20T14:58:00'\G
>   *************************** 1. row ***************************
>              id: 1   select_type: SIMPLE
>           table: channeldata
>   partitions: NULL
>            type: ref
>    possible_keys: PRIMARY,composite3,composite
>             key: PRIMARY
>         key_len: 4
>             ref: const,const
>            rows: 176539
>        filtered: 33.33
>           Extra: Using index condition 1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
>
> mysql> explain SELECT reading FROM channeldata WHERE station_id = 6001
>   AND channel_id = 4 AND time < '2018-09-20T14:58:00'\G
>   *************************** 1. row ***************************
>              id: 1   select_type: SIMPLE
>           table: channeldata
>   partitions: NULL
>            type: range
>   possible_keys: PRIMARY,composite3,composite
>             key: PRIMARY
>         key_len: 9
>             ref: NULL
>            rows: 428073
>        filtered: 100.00
>           Extra: Using index condition 1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Why would filtering for a different value (channel_id is 4 instead of 1) make a difference? Both result sets are equal in size. Why is it that on both occasions MySQL chooses to use the PRIMARY key, but that the keylen differs significantly.

Comment: You use many fields in keys and they intersect thus giving a lot of work for MySQL inner optimizer (that's why explain shows all 3 possible keys used in select). Try to minimize usage of fields in keys and combine them only when it's necessary and seems logical

Comment: Another problem of using a lot of keys (and badly constructed) is that indexing process starts overwhelm caching possibilities of MySQL itself. In such case you need to perform OPTIMIZE TABLE command or refer to MySQL settings

Comment: why would the `PRIMARY` key have a key_len of both 4 and 9 ? That looks strange. Also 4 looks really small for a 3 column key. Smallint takes 2 bytes and datetime takes 5 bytes so keylen should have been 9 in both cases. No idea why this would happen though.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't come up with the design of the table. Could you elaborate as to why these keys are badly constructed Anton? The composite keys are there to speed up other queries we use on this table and they seem to work very well.

Answer (score 1):

You have a **bug**.  The `T` in the time constant is not recognized by MySQL; change it to a space.

You should switch to **InnoDB**.

In MyISAM, **this** would speed up the query:

```
INDEX(channel_id, station_id,  -- in either order
      time,
      reading)   -- last
```

That would be "covering", hence faster than bounding back and forth between the index and the data.

Back to **why** they are different...  I don't know.  However, either of these *may* help with a MyISAM table:  `ANALYZE TABLE` or `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.

Comment: Good grief. Thanks for pointing it out. I have used ISO8601 timestamps in WHERE clauses (and INSERTS/UPDATES) before and never noticed any problems.